# angular-cli - ZoneAwareError when trying to add a second stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, sass, angular-cli

I have several issues with trying to add a second stylesheet to my angular-cli app.

**Problem #1:**

I have a stylesheet which has a dot in it's name. `mystyle.thestyle.scss` This is loaded from a component using "styleUrls". Right now this is loading before the default `styles.scss`. **Which is not what I want.**

I want it to load after the default `styles.scss` file so I did this in my angular-cli.json file,

```
"styles": [
        "src/styles/styles.scss",
        "src/styles/mystyle.thestyle.scss"
      ],
```

When I do that this error shows in the browser:

> ZoneAwareError
>
> __zone_symbol__error : Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings. at assertArrayOfStrings...

**Problem #2:**

When I rename `mystyle.thestyle.scss` to `mystyle.scss` I don't get that error. But the problem is, mystyle.scss does not load after styles.scss.

If I have a variable $color: blue in styles.scss and use it in mystyle.scss, it throws an error saying it cannot find that variable.

**What I want:**

All I want to do is, load `styles.scss` (which will import my variables and mixins) before `mystyle.thestyle.scss`. Why can't I do this?

And why can't I use my scss file which has a dot in it's name?

I'm very new to angular-cli and I'm very confused.

Comment: did you miss a comma within your styleUrls array declaration?

Comment: Sorry. The comma is there. Let me edit my answer

Comment: What's the CLI version you're using? Solved this?

Comment: @SaiyaffFarouk Hi! No it's not solved. This is my angular version: angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1

Comment: Both kinda scenarios are working in my app. Just tested them. v1.0.0-rc.2